# require.js dependencies - how to incorporate dependency methods in additional script

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, dependencies

I'm using raphael.js in a backbone.js project.  Importing raphael works like a charm (this version is AMD compliant). Everything is working as expected.  "app" here is a predefined global object defined in another app.js file.

define(['jquery', 'underscore', 'app', 'backbone','raphael'  ], 
function($, _, app, Backbone, Raphael) {

```
var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({

initialize: function() { 

    app.paper = Raphael(0, 0, app.w, app.h);
```

}
   ...
   }) })

Now my app.paper has all Raphael methods. Awesome!

I just discovered in the Raphael API that I can add my own predefined methods using Raphael.el and Raphael.fn

```
initialize: function() { 

    app.paper = Raphael(0, 0, app.w, app.h);

    Raphael.el.myfill = function(){
        this.attr('fill', '90-#fff-#000');
    }

    app.paper.circle(x,y,r).myfill(); //it works! (Brilliant!)

    }
```

}

My question is, how can I put the Raphael.el.myfill definition along with other    Raphael.fn.mydefinedmethods into another javascript file and bring it into the AppView above?

I don't want to clog up my AppView file with lengthy definitions, and I also would like to provide variability as to which Raphael.[el|fn] definitions I use in different views.  But since these object constructors are already part of the Raphael.js object that I've already pulled in as a dependency, I'm not sure how to separate the Raphael.el and Raphael.fn definitions out using the require.js protocol. Before require.js I would have simply put such definitions in another myRaphaelDefs.js file, added another "script" tag to my html and they'd all be available always, but this is the 2015 and I've jumped on the modular js bandwagon.

I'm using RedRaphael branch which is AMD compliant, so I have no "define" wrapper on the Raphael.js itself.  If this library did come with such a wrapper I might try adding the outsourced definitions directly into the Raphael.js as dependencies. (not an option) RedRaphael works with require.js right out of the box, so there's no "define" wrapper there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What we do is add a wrapper around our libraries and route it with the `map` option in require.config, so the wrapper gets the original library, but everything else goes throw the wrapper:

raphael-wrapper.js:

```
define(['raphael'], function (Raphael) {
    Raphael.el.myfill = function(){
        this.attr('fill', '90-#fff-#000');
    };
    return Raphael;
});
```

require.config:

```
{
    paths: {
        'raphael': '/path/to/rahpael'
    },
    map: {
        '*': {
            'raphael': '/path/to/rahpael-wrapper'
        },
        '/path/to/rahpael-wrapper': {
            'raphael': 'raphael'
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Uzi.  I've not used the map option before. Ok I'll try that.

Comment: Awesome, it works! Glad I asked because I didn't see anything explaining this kind of situation in the require.js API